# Xcode Validation Receipt Signature Error

Tags: ios, xcode, validation

I'm in the process of using in-app purchase in my App... now I want to validate the receipt, and for validating receipt signature I use the below code in the AppDelegate (in order to know if the user already purchased it when launching the App)

actually the code comes from the WWDC 2013 - session 308 ;-)

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppleIncRootCertificate" withExtension:@"cer"]];

/* The PKCS #7 container (the receipt) and The Apple root certificate. */
BIO *b_receipt = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *) [receiptData bytes], (int)[receiptData length]);
BIO *b_x509 = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[certificateData bytes], (int)[certificateData length]);

// Convert receipt data to PKCS #7 Representation
PKCS7 *p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(b_receipt, NULL);

/* Create the root certificate */
X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
X509 *appleRootCA = d2i_X509_bio(b_x509, NULL);
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, appleRootCA);

/* Verify the signature. If the verification is correct, b_receiptPayload will contain the PKCS #7 payload and result will be 1. */
BIO *b_receiptPayload = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
int result = PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, b_receiptPayload, 0);
if (result == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Receipt Signature is valid");
} else {
    unsigned long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_str = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    NSLog(@"OpenSSL Error: %s",error_str);
}
```

but I always get the following OpenSSL Error: error:2006F079:lib(32):func(111):reason(121)

I already google it but without any result...any suggestion?

Another way to validate receipt signature?

thank you in advance for your cooperation...

Comment: I use this library - https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore. Here is information how to use receipt verification https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/wiki/Receipt-verification

Comment: thank you, I'll check it...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

two things here:

1) I forgot to add the "AppleIncRootCertificate.cer" to my app's resource bundle, this is, to my project and obviously this is a mandatory.

2) The below code line is necessary too:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

(or OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); instead?)

and it has to be placed before

```
int result = PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, b_receiptPayload, 0);
```

now is working...

PS: by the way, it is a good idea to use this below code line in Terminal (in order to know what the error refers to):

```
openssl errstr "errornumber" (i.e.openssl errstr 2006F079)
```